# JavaScript errors in IE10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

It seems like quite a lot of JavaScript functionality is broken using [internet-explorer-10](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10) on [windows-8-preview](/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview).  For instance, Facebook flakes out on me, not letting me add comments, and StackOverflow/SuperUser doesn't let me vote.  If you are reading this question, however, then it seems I am able to post a question.

Is there a way to report these kinds of errors, or does anyone know a way around them?

For the record, these JavaScript errors are still present in Windows 8 RTM. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit feedback on Internet Explorer 10 on the [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE) platform.

Comment: It seems kinda silly to me - you have to login to Microsoft Connect from the Windows 8 computer.  Seems like every time I'm ready to report this error, I'm not on my Windows 8 laptop.

Comment: No, You don't have to report the problem with Windows 8. At least I think that everytime I have reported something I've done it using Firefox on Windows 7. Anyway, don't put too much hopes on your reports, it's almost sure that they will be closed as "working as expected" or "this is by design", so it's not really worth wasting the time to report them anything.